# How to remove comment "Created with Jaspersoft Studio version.."?

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

Is it a way to avoid the version comment to be added?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.1  -->
```

Not the whole team use the exact same version, some have 6.4, 6.5, 6.5.1, so this comment generate unnecessary changes on Git

Comment: Five years on, did you manage to solve this problem? If you did, could you share how you did it?

Comment: No, we all agreed to use the same version, no happy ending

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a simple solution.

As a workaround, force the jrxml and compiler versions on Window > Preferences > Jasper Studio > Compatibility to a desired version. This way, the comment will still be there but will always be the same